# Microservices in AKS Azure with Loadbalancer integration

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-cloud-services

My company wants to migrate from kubernetes on-premise into AKS Azure Cloud. We have arround 120 microservices in on-premise.

I want suggestions for the deployment in AKS Azure with Loadbalancer integrated to each microservices deployed.

After i deploy some microservices, e.g microservice A, and B in separated namespace.

How do i set the Loadbalancer(Front) connected to AKS(Backend), e.g

```
www.domain.tld/a will be forwarded to microservice a
www.domain.tld/b will be forwarded to microservice b
```

What additional stack should i use to implement custom host loadbalancer in Azure ?

Any suggestions or articles about this really help me to plan this migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very broad question, however you are looking for something like [NGNIX ingress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) or [`Application gateway ingress controller`](https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/) which allows the gateway to load-balance traffic to Kubernetes pods.

Comment: Do we really need external stack like nginx ingress controller yeah ? I thought, Azure Loadbalancer can replace it. But thank you for your suggestion. This is really important for me.

Comment: Yes you can use it  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/load-balancer-standard